# Fabric2 get file raises IsADirectoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I am trying to convert Fabric 1 to Fabric 2 script and I have the following statement to get the remote file:

```
c.get(os.path.join(working_dir, "dist/*.tar.gz"), "dist"))
```

It used to work just fine, copy a file from remote computer to a local directory called dist. However, with Fabric2 it fails with

```
"IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/rapolas/projects/dist'"
```

Sure enough, it is a directory, but that is exactly what I want, to put that remote file (there is only one, but I don't have its name) into local directory. According to [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/api/transfer.html#fabric.transfer.Transfer.get):

> For example, if the local path is a directory, the remote path’s base filename will be added onto it (so get('foo/bar/file.txt', '/tmp/') would result in creation or overwriting of /tmp/file.txt).

but for some reason, it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By any chance, how did you resolved the issue ?
Same issue is with get() with Fabric 2 package ?

Comment: I ended up listing remote dir, getting the filename and putting full file paths in the get command: `result = c.run("ls " + cwd + "/dist/"); fname = result.stdout.strip(); c.get(cwd + "/dist/" + fname, os.path.join(DEFAULT_DIST_DIR, fname))`.

Comment: There is a bug report: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1998

Comment: Was filed by me :)

Comment: The problem I think is that the get method won't create directories if they don't exist. So localpath='/tmp/foo.txt' works and localpath='/tmp/bar/foo.txt' (bar does not exists) fails.